# ul li wider than browser window force onto new line for pagination

Tags: css

How can I make ul li pagination menu break onto a new line when it wider than the browser window, it works Ok on desktop ,but on mobile devices it is wider than the browser window.

I have tried

> 'overflow-x: hidden'

but this does not work as the window still scrolls horizontally, I've tried

> display inline-block

, but that just stacks the list vertically.

Any help would be appreciated

> Site would not allow me to add code earlier, said too much code not
>   enough text

-------------CSS------------------

```
.page-item:first-child .page-link {
    border-top-left-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
}


.page-item.active .page-link {
    z-index: 1;
    color: #282d32;
    background-color: #acacac !important;
    border-color: #acacac !important;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.page-link:not(:disabled):not(.disabled) {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.page-link {
    display: block;
    padding: .5rem .75rem;
    margin-left: -1px;
    line-height: 1.25;
    color: #282d32 !important;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
    margin: 5px;
    border-radius: 25px;
}

.page-item:last-child .page-link {
    border-top-right-radius: 25px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
}
```

---------HTML---------------------

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
                <ul class="pagination">
                        <li class="page-item active">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">2</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">3</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">4</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">5</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">6</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">7</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">8</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">9</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="page-item ">
                            <a class="page-link" href="/">10</a>
                        </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Comment: Do you have some example of your code to show us?

Comment: pls share the codes which you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **css flexbox** which will help you get the desired output , just make the display of the **ul** to flex and use the property flex-wrap : wrap ; also on the parent **ul** element and at any time when the li while break onto new line when the ul is wider than the window view port

look at the example below ,

you can learn more
[guid-to-css-flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```css
ul {
list-style:none; 
display:flex;
flex-wrap : wrap;
}
li {
width:100px ;
height:100px; 
border-radius : 3px ; 
background-color : red; 
margin:4px ;
text-align : center ;
}
```

```html
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
<li>4</li>
<li>5</li>
<li>6</li>
<li>7</li>
<li>8</li>
<li>9</li>
<li>10</li>
<li>11</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Take that back, it working now, was not working earlier

Comment: flex box is amazing for one direction layout  , you can use it to control your layout as you want